# reopen program when it is crashed

Tags: raspbian, script, deluge

Deluge torrent client crashes randomly. And i could not find the core reason. So are there any script that reopen a program when it is crashed. Or it can check is it working and if not runs that program.

Answer (score 2):

I personally use this bash script:

```
while :
do
deluge-gtk #or whatever program you wish to run.
sleep 2
done
```

**Note:** This does NOT work for non-blocking programs, instead it would launch them an infinite amount of time. (Deluge is fine.)

***Script explanation***

This is an infinite loop. Inside the loop the program runs, if the program crashes, the script will sleep for 2 seconds and then jump to the beginning of the program, hence restarting Deluge. The 2 second sleep is a fail-safe so that in case the program is crashing upon startup, your CPU doesn't get overloaded.

***setting up the script in Raspberry Pi***

1. Copy the script above into a text editor such as leafpad and save it. In this example we will save it as `/home/pi/run_forever.sh`
2. execute the following in a terminal:

.

```
cd /home/pi
chmod +x run_forever.sh
```

Your script is ready. to run it, type this in a terminal:

```
/home/pi/run_forever.sh
```

Comment: it says deluge-gtk: not found. i use deluged command to open deluge. will this cause a problem while it is a infinite loop?

Comment: After typing "deluged" Does your terminal block?  If the answer is yes, then you are safe doing this.

Comment: no it is not. i understood your approach. i will search a command that runs deluge without exiting the loop. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively do a check to see if the program is running before you run it
Save this file in `/opt/scripts/` as checkdeluge.sh for example.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $(pidof deluge | wc -l) -eq 0 ]]; then
    deluge # or whatever program here
fi
```

Make the script executable - `chmod 755 /opt/scripts/checkdeluge.sh`

Then add a cronjob to run this every minute with `crontab` using the following line

```
* * * * * /opt/scripts/checkdeluge.sh
```

*Update*
An alternative could be as simple as putting this into the crontab -

```
* * * * * pidof deluge > /dev/null || deluge
```

Comment: i think double parenthesis "[[" causes an error. however i tried one parenthesis and if condition being executed always whether deluge is on run or not.

Comment: What error ? I tested it on a debian machine and it worked

Comment: it says `checkdeluge.sh: 2: checkdeluge.sh: [[: not found`

Comment: What shell are you running ? and what Distro ?

Comment: i am using terminal of os X and debian as distro

Comment: Debian/Raspbian Wheezy or Jessie ? I just tested it on my Pi running Raspbian and [[ does not present an issue. Do you have the `#!/bin/bash` at the beginning of the script ?

Comment: Raspbian wheezy. and yes i have #!/bin/bash. but my script file is at root folder. does that cause any problem?

Comment: It shouldn't do...can you paste the entire contents of the script onto pastebin and link it ?